# Show that $ X_p = ( \ell^1 , \| \cdot \|_p ) \subset (\ell^p, \| \cdot\|_p )$ is banach space

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

tried to consider a series absolutely convergent with  $\|\cdot\|_p$ and show that it is absolutely convergent with $\|\cdot\|_1$, that would solve the problem, because $(\ell^1,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is banach.  But I couldn't finish anything, could someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false.  Consider the sequence $ \mathbf{a}_n \in \ell^1 $ given by
$$
\mathbf{a}_n = \langle a^n_i \rangle_{i=1}^\infty \quad a^n_i = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{i^{1/(p-1)}} &\mbox{if } i \leq n \\
0 & \mbox{if } i > n \end{cases}
$$
Define
$$
\mathbf{a}^* = \left\langle \frac{1}{i^{1/(p-1)}} \right\rangle_{i=1}^{\infty}
$$
Then we have $ \ell^1 \ni \mathbf{a}_n \rightarrow \mathbf{a}^* \in \ell^p $ with convergence in $ \ell^p $-norm, but $ \mathbf{a}^* \notin \ell^1 $.  Thus $ \langle \mathbf{a}_n \rangle $ is a Cauchy sequence in $ (\ell^1, \| \cdot \|_p)$ which doesn't have a limit in this space.